# How do I redirect my page with web.config

Tags: azure, redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

I want to redirect my sites main **tiptilepro.com** to my a subdirection **tiptilepro.com/pro/editor**.

I have this code but it is not working:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to sub" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^*.tiptilepro.com$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/tiptilepro.com/pro/editor" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The user should see the content of the subfolder tiptilepro.com/pro/editor, but in the adress bar the main url: tiptilepro.com

**Edit:**
I've now put `if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="www.tiptilepro.com") header('Location: pro/editor');` in my index file, can I let the adress bar show just "www.tiptilepro.com"?

Comment: Do you want to Rewrite or do you want to redirect. Thats two different things.

Comment: My content is in the pro/editor folder, I would like to have the url tiptilepro.com to show the content.

Comment: Then you dont need any of them. Then you should just fix the routing in your app so that it displays what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RedirectToNewURL" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(tiptilepro.com/)$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://tiptilepro.com/pro/editor" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
<rewrite>
```

But what you need to do is fix your routing in your application. E.g. in .NET Core / MVC you could just add the proper routing in your Startup.cs file.

```
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=pro}/{action=editor}/{id?}");
```

Comment: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.